# State are not going back to initial state in react component

Tags: reactjs

```
1.created a component with few states
2.in componentDidMount updated state with some lists checkbox values 
3.due to onChange of checkbox i will update values in state
4.now i will redirect to some other page
5.if i render the same component in other page it has preserved the state, it had not went back to initial state
```

my quetsion is why componentDidMount block doesn't update the states with fresh values

```
state = {
checkBoxes:[]
}
componentDidMount(){
  setState({checkBoxes: getCheckBoxes()})
}
```

Comment: my states are actually like state = {
    first:[{id:1
        'checked' : false
    },{id:2
        'checked' : false
    }]
this is the reason it's not working, but how to overcome this problem

Comment: could you please post some more code? I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: i got answer to my problem actually i created nested state and its not recommanded in react component

Comment: actually it's not a problem at all, i use them often, but i use Hooks and abandoned class components! You have just have to understand what your goal is, but i'm happy you could solve your issue